# Why does Google Cast iOS SDK crash on beginSessionWithConfiguration?

Tags: ios, google-cast

Cast SDK seems to crash inside beginSessionWithConfiguration for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you share the same Google Cast App ID across two iOS client apps, the second one to connect to a Cast will crash. Simply restart the Google Cast between running your two different client apps to resolve this issue. And obviously never ship two apps with the same Google Cast App ID in production.

Comment: Also note there are errors like this when using Remote Display. Best I can tell they should just be ignored: `[0822/004423:ERROR:audio_encoder.cc(641)] Not implemented reached in static OSStatus media::cast::AudioEncoder::AppleAacImpl::FileSetSizeCallback(void *, SInt64)`